# Activator.CreateInstance creates value of type T instead of Nullable<T>

Tags: c#, activator

Look at the sample code below

```
var genericNullableType = typeof(Nullable<>);
var nullableType = genericNullableType.MakeGenericType(typeof(bool));
var returnValue = Activator.CreateInstance(nullableType, (object)false);
```

For some reason `returnValue` variable will be of type `bool` and not `bool?`. Why is that and how could it be avoided?

UPD: Here is a screenshot from my VS
[image]

Comment: @petelids I'm using VS 2013 Premium and .NET Framework 4.5 and build configuration is Debug. Do you use the same configuration?

Comment: This isn't unique to `Activator`. `Console.WriteLine((new Nullable<bool>(false).GetType().FullName));` also just spits out plain Boolean.

Comment: There is no way to get a boxed nullable. The runtime has special handling for nullable boxing and will always unwrap it into a boxed value of the underlying type or a null reference. That said it should be castable as a `bool?` so I'm not sure what you are looking for.

Comment: Here is relevant blog post by Brad Wilson [Creating `Nullable<T>` When You Don't Know T](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2008/07/creating-nullab.html)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In this particular case you are using the overload of `CreateInstance` which returns `object`.  The `Nullable<T>` is a `struct` hence to be represented as `object` it would need to be boxed.  Yet `Nullable<T>` can't actually be boxed by rules of the CLR.  Instead the underlying value or `null` is used.  This is why you get a raw `bool` back here instead of `bool?`.

Documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228597.aspx

**EDIT**

There seems to be some confusion around determining whether the type of a value is nullable or not.  In particular it's been pointed out that the following prints `System.Boolean` and not ``` System.Nullable``1[System.Boolean] ```:

```
var x = (bool?)true;
Console.WriteLine(x.GetType());
```

This code is also falling prey to boxing.  The call to `GetType` has an implicit boxing operation because it's an invocation of a virtual method on `object`, not a method on `Nullable<T>`:

```
IL_0009: ldloc.0
IL_000a: box valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<bool>
IL_000f: call instance class [mscorlib]System.Type [mscorlib]System.Object::GetType()
IL_0014: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(object)
```

The safest way to print out the actual type of a `var` value is to do the following trick with generics:

```
static void PrintType<T>(T value)
{
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(T));
}

PrintType(x);  // Prints System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]
```

Comment: Even if another overload of CreateInstance was used, GetType would still internally box because it is non-virtual, thus you would never see a `Nullable<T>` out of GetType, correct?

Comment: @mikez correct.  The call to `GetType()` generates an implicit `.box` il opcode which prevents it from spitting out the nullable type.  To get the true type to print you need to use generics.  Will demonstrate that in just a sec.